# Error on ConfigureAwait(false)

Tags: c#, json, api

I am trying to retrieve some data from an API, the following is my piece of code that makes the request after authenticating and assigning the completed URL.

```
public async Task<T> GetAPIData<T>(string url)
{
    using (var client = HttpClientSetup())
    {
        var response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);

         var JsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
         return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JsonResponse);
    }
}

private HttpClient HttpClientSetup()
{
    var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(apiBaseUrl) };
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = authenticationHeader;
    return client;
}
```

I am getting an error on the line with `ConfigureAwait(false);`
 as

> "HTTPResponseMessage does not contain a definition for ConfigureAwait"

. Could anyone help me as to what might be going wrong?

Comment: You have two calls to `ConfigureAwait(false)` - which is causing the problem?

Comment: The body of the `using` statement compiles fine for me though - can you produce a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for your reply. The first call assigning to response is throwing the error.

Comment: Right - well I don't understand why it would be doing that, given that the same code works fine for me. Again, please provide a [mcve] - along with details of your environment. (What kind of project is this? What version of the framework are you building against?)

Comment: Only the first one is showing an error? Which version of .Net Framework are you using? Is it an older one?

Comment: @Jon and David, thanks both. I changed the version of the framework for the project from 4.5.1 to 4.6.1 and now it compiles fine!